# Table rows count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running the following query and checking whether it returns any results and if not I need implement some logic in my sp. I have given couple of code blocks below from my sp.

```
select * from temp
where (select * table1 where Id='4728')=0
```

If the table1 doesnt have any records it shouldn't return any results and I need to know whether I am checking it correctly.

```
INSERT INTO #companies
    SELECT DISTINCT c.Company_Id
    FROM COMPANY C
        INNER JOIN Request_Summary rs ON c.Company_ID=rs.Company_ID
        WHERE
            rs.IsMember_Ind <> 0            
            AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Monitor_Request mr WHERE mr.Company_ID=c.Company_ID)< 5
                       -- I am checking it here
            AND EXISTS(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Monitor_Request mr2 WHERE mr2.Company_ID=c.Company_ID)
            AND NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT * FROM TaskAction ta WHERE 
                ta.FirstActionTypeId = @firstActionTypeId and 
                ta.TaskTypeId = @taskTypeId and 
                ta.NextActionTypeId is not null and
                ta.EntityId = c.Company_ID and
                ta.EntityTypeId = 1)
```

Comment: Do you have to check this explicitly?  Can we see the whole SP?  Depending on what you're attempting to do, you may not need to explicitly check for existence - especially if you're dealing with concurrent access.

Comment: added the code. and commented here I need to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the table1 doesnt have any records it shouldn't return any results

Since you're in a Stored Procedure and you may just want to do this

```
IF Exists(select * table1 where Id='4728')
BEGIN 
     Select...

END
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `WHERE EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM temp 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE Id='4728'
)
```

Comment: +1 - pretty much where I was headed, although I tend to prefer constant values (`'1'`, which evaluates to true in RPG...) instead of `SELECT *` in the `EXISTS` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table1 WHERE Id='4728') = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM temp
END
```

and yet another solution, as pruposed by Aaron at the comments:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE Id='4728')
BEGIN 
     SELECT * FROM temp
END
```

Comment: Great solution because it decouples the relationship between table1 and temp.

Comment: Wasn't me, but I'm not fond of this answer because getting a count is *potentially* much less efficient than checking for existence. While `Id` may be the primary key, it isn't necessarily the case, and future readers may think getting an expensive count is worthwhile even when they only care whether the count is 0 or 1.  `EXISTS` can be no more inefficient than getting a count, so I would prefer Conrad's approach over this one, always.

Comment: @AaronBertrand nice thought, just updated to put that solution as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think I'd restructure that query to something like this:

```
INSERT INTO #companies
SELECT c.company_Id  -- presumes that company_Id is DISTINCT initially
FROM Company c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT '1'
              FROM Request_Summary s
              WHERE s.company_Id = c.company_Id
              AND s.isMember_Ind <> 0)
AND EXISTS (SELECT '1'
            FROM Monitor_Request m
            WHERE m.company_Id = c.company_Id
            GROUP BY m.company_Id
            HAVING COUNT(*) < 5)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                FROM TaskAction t
                WHERE ta.FirstActionTypeId = @firstActionTypeId 
                AND t.TaskTypeId = @taskTypeId 
                AND t.NextActionTypeId IS NOT NULL 
                AND t.EntityId = c.Company_ID 
                AND t.EntityTypeId = 1)
```

Don't ever bother with a `SELECT COUNT(*)` inside a `WHERE EXISTS` clause, as the optimizer will *potentially* count all rows (even if we only care about one).  If a `JOIN` is giving you more than one row, but you're only checking for existence (ie, you don't need any data from it), use an `EXISTS` clause.

I was actually curious about your entire SP, not just this query -  especially as you're inserting into a session/temp table.  Is this something that should be turned into a CTE?